# Determining #Buckets for Hive's Bucketed Join

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

I have multiple tables Table A, Table B, and Table C. I want to be able to use Hive's bucketed map join. I am aware that buckets for A, B, C should be multiples of each other.

Is there a general rule on estimating the required #buckets while creating the tables so as to ensure a map-side join?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Bucket Map Join in production, so just some inference based on bucket map join's principle.

In Bucket Join, correlated buckets from both tables are join together, using small table's bucket to build hashtable, and iterate the large table's bucket file one by one in original order, probe the hash table in memory and generate join results.

So, I think `small table's each bucket should be small enough to put in memory` (map slot's heap size you set in mapred-site.xml). the bigger the small table is, the more buckets you should set for it.

I think big table's bucket number can be arbitrary number, just multiple of small table's bucket number.